# Create Animation from Array of images

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble taking 6 photos and storing them in an object array in order to animate them. I keep getting an error saying:

> Array index out of range

Also, I realized that the "image" object isn't recognized outside the if-statement for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){

    var picArray: [UIImage] = []

    for index in 1...6 {

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                    if sampleBuffer != nil {


                        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                        let dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                        let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

                        let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                        self.tempImageView.image = image
                        self.tempImageView.hidden = false

                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

                        picArray[index] = image;
                    }

            })

        }
    }
    self.gifView.animationImages = picArray;
    self.gifView.animationDuration = 1.0
    self.gifView.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Your `picArray` is empty, and you're trying to set the elements at given indices that don't exist – did you mean to use `.append()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`picArray` is empty, so you shouldn't use `insert` method. instead you have to use the `append` method.

The reason why is `picArray` is empty you are inserting the values inside the `asynchronous` block. The for loop completes before inserting images because it doesn't wait for asynchronous blocks to be complete.

You have to wait for `asynchronous` block to be complete before animating the image view.

You can achieve this using `dispatch_group`

```
 func didPressTakePhoto(){

    var picArray: [UIImage] = []

    let dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()

    for index in 1...6 {

        dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup)

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
            videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
                (sampleBuffer, error) in

                if sampleBuffer != nil {


                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)

                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                    self.tempImageView.image = image
                    self.tempImageView.hidden = false

                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

                    picArray.append(image);
                }

                dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup)

            })

        } else {
            dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup)
        }
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.gifView.animationImages = picArray;
        self.gifView.animationDuration = 1.0
        self.gifView.startAnimating()
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.